# Getting the pom for a dependency in Gradle

Tags: gradle

In resolving a dependency from a Maven-repository, Gradle has to download the corresponding pom-file. I would like to access this file from within the Gradle-script and save it somewhere. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [Artifact Query API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.query.ArtifactResolutionQuery.html). Here is the sample code (Groovy):

```
def componentIds = configurations.compileClasspath.incoming.resolutionResult.allDependencies.collect { it.selected.id }
def result = project.dependencies.createArtifactResolutionQuery()
        .forComponents(componentIds)
        .withArtifacts(MavenModule, MavenPomArtifact)
        .execute()
for (component in result.resolvedComponents) {
    component.getArtifacts(MavenPomArtifact).each { println "POM file for ${component.id}: ${it.file}" }
}
```

I'm using the same API in [my plugin in Kotlin](https://github.com/kropp/gradle-plugin-thanks/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/github/kropp/gradle/thanks/ThanksPlugin.kt#L70).

Answer (score 2):

You could simply declare a dependency on the POM itself.

```
configurations {
    pom
}


dependencies {
    pom 'org.foo:some-lib:1.0.0@pom'
}

task copyPom(type: Copy) {
    into "${buildDir}/poms"
    from configurations.pom
}
```

If you want the aar and jar dependencies, not the pom itself, you can use the above, except omit the @pom specifier in the dependencies. You can also have both of these simultaneously.

```
    pom 'org.foo:some-lib:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted actually to get the dependencies from the existing poms rather than having to reconstruct them by hand. I have found a completely different solution to the original problem, though.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @user2615350 And that solution would be?

Comment: If you want to fetch the libraries, not the POM itself, you can just remove the "@pom" part from the 'dependencies' line and it will fetch those.  Or get both by adding two pom dependencies:  pom 'org.foo:some-lib:1.0.0@pom'  and pom 'org.foo:some-lib:1.0.0'